# Is QWebView class working in Qt 5.0.0?

Tags: javascript, performance, qt, qtwebkit, qt5

Need your help! We had a problem regarding the slow rendering of the text by JavaScript on Qt 4.8. Therefore we decided to rebuild the project on Qt 5.0.0 Beta as far as in the documentation it was written that Qt 5.0 is using V8 Javascript Engine that should fasten up the javascript code in our windows application.

But the PROBLEM is how to run the build on V8? Besides in the Class Index (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/classes.html) of Qt 5.0 there is no QWebView at all.

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 5):

New webkit shipping with QT5 has a new structure. QWebView, QWebpage, etc. are now part of QtWebKitWidgets.

So in your code you need to include webview like this:

```
  #include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
```

and in your .pro file your need to add:

```
   QT += webkitwidgets
```

If you really want to make your code forward/backwards compatible; I would just have a check for QT5:

```
QT+= core gui webkit

contains(QT_VERSION, ^5.*) {
    QT += webkitwidgets
}
```

...

and then in your code:

```
#if (QT_VERSION < 0x050000)
#include <QWebView>
#else
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
#endif
```